# Property of asymptotic notation little $o$ in limits.

Tags: limits, asymptotics, definition

For example, we have a limit

$$\lim_{x\to1} \:\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}=A$$

and we know that as $x\rightarrow 0$ we have  $$\ln(x)= x-1 +o(x-1), \qquad \text{(1)}$$ which by definition means:

$$\lim_{x\to1} \:\frac{\ln(x)-(x-1)}{x-1}=0.$$

I know that by knowing this definition and using some limit properties we can get the answer $A$.
But are we allowed to just change the limit (by plugging in (1))? Namely to the following one:

$$\lim_{x\to1} \:\frac{x-1 +o(x-1)}{1-x}=-1=A$$

and proceed to solve this limit. What are the justifications by their limit definitions?

This example might be too simple, but what I want to point out is that, most of the times it is easier to plug in (1) and solve the limit than to write out the definition of (1) and do algebraic manipulations and by using some limit properties to get the answer $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first rewrite the definition of what it means for something to be ‘little-oh’ of something else. We say *$f$ is little-oh $g$ as $x$ goes to $a$* iff $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0,$$ and we write $$f(x) = o(g(x)) \quad \text{as } x\rightarrow a.$$ Even more formally, $o(x)$ represents a set, and we should write $f(x) \in o(g(x)).$ Hence when we write \begin{equation} \log(x) = x-1 + o(x-1), \end{equation} what we really mean is \begin{equation} \log(x) = x-1 + f(x-1), \end{equation} for $f(x-1) \in o(x-1)$ as $x-1 \rightarrow 0.$ Now writing out your limit, we get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\log(x)}{1-x} = \lim_{x-1\rightarrow 0} \frac{x-1+f(x-1)}{1-x} \\
= -1 - \lim_{x-1\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x-1)}{x-1} = -1,$$ which is the same result as if you had simply plugged in $\log(x) = x-1 + o(x-1).$

From this, you should be able to see *why* you are justified in using the $o(x)$ notation: because it's a useful shorthand for something more formal.  As long as you remember what the notation stands for, you should be able to manipulate it sensibly.

---

Edit: further clarifications.  One thing that might also help is if you consider the change of variables $x-1 \mapsto y.$  Copying the above paragraphs with this transformation gives the following.

> When we write \begin{equation} \log(y+1) = y + o(y), \end{equation} what we really mean is \begin{equation} \log(y+1) = y + f(y), \end{equation} for $f(y) \in o(y)$ as $y \rightarrow 0.$ Now writing out your limit, we get $$\lim_{y+1\rightarrow 1} \frac{\log(y+1)}{-y} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{y+f(y)}{-y} \\
> = -1 - \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(y)}{y} = -1,$$ which is the same result as if you had simply plugged in $\log(y+1) = y + o(y).$

---

Edit (ii): clarification regarding the definition of a limit.  By definition, $$\lim_{y\rightarrow b} h(y) = B \Longleftrightarrow \\ (\forall \epsilon > 0) (\exists \delta > 0)(\left\|{y-b}\right\| < \delta \Rightarrow  \left\|{h(y)-B}\right\| < \epsilon).$$

Comment: We know that $log(x)=x-1+o(x-1) \: as\: x\rightarrow1$ , but the sign $x\rightarrow1$ doesn't has the same definition with the one we have in the limit, right? So how are we justified plugging it in the limit?

Comment: The limit as $x\rightarrow 1$ is the same as the limit as $x-1 \rightarrow 0,$ which matches the definition given at the start.  Does that make sense?  I'll add in some clarifications.

Comment: I'm still confused, since the definition of $x\rightarrow1$ in the $log(x)$ is not the same as the one in the limit (How is it written in the definition of the limit? Intuitively speaking, it makes sense, but I don't know how it fit in the definition), so how are we justified to connect both of them by plugging in $x-1+o(x-1)$ to $log(x)$. Yes please add in some clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: I've read your edit, what is the meaning of $log(y+1)=y+f(y)\:for\:f(y)\in o(y)\:as\:y\rightarrow0$ formally? How does it fit to the ordinary limit definition of $y\rightarrow0$, more clearly, how can we be sure that the statement, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that  $\left|\frac{y+f(y)}{-y}-A\right|< \epsilon \quad$ whenever$ \quad0<\left|y\right|<\delta$ is true.

Comment: I'm not sure understand the question.  *By definition,* $$\lim_{y\rightarrow b} h(y) = B \Longleftrightarrow \\ (\forall \epsilon > 0) (\exists \delta > 0)(\left\|{y-b}\right\| < \delta \Rightarrow  \left\|{h(y)-B}\right\| < \epsilon).$$ So by using the additive property of limits, $$\lim \left(\frac{y+f(y)}{-y}\right) = \lim\left(-1-\frac{f(y)}{y} \right) = -1 - \lim \frac{f(y)}{y}.$$

Comment: Sorry, above comment isn't clear.  What I meant is that perhaps you're confused by the use of the additive property of limits.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my question was not clear, my question was, why are we allowed to substitute $y+f(y)$ for $log(y+1)$, how is this seen in the definition of limit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95428/discussion-between-confusedandbemused-and-hteica).

Comment: But you are currently not there, can we use latex in chatrooms?